# How to filter not valid locations update iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm using CCLocationManager to track location every 1 minutes, here is my didUpdateLocation delegate method :

```
func changeLocationAccuracy() {
    switch locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
    case kCLLocationAccuracyBest:
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 99999
    case kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers:
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    default: break
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let newLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    let interval = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

    if abs(interval) > 5 || locationManager.desiredAccuracy != kCLLocationAccuracyBest {
        return
    }

    if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
        return
    }

    if currentLocation != nil && newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(currentLocation.timestamp) < 0 {
        return
    }

    currentLocation = newLocation

    print("interval: \(interval)")
    print("desiredAccuracy: \(locationManager.desiredAccuracy)")
    print("accuracy: \(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)")

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(LocationService.changeLocationAccuracy), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    changeLocationAccuracy()
}
```

As you can see above i'm filtering out invalid location but the problem is my distance is changing without moving my phone. Here is my log data :

```
interval: -0.0140599608421326
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 90.8123422472749
distance : 113.473282606026
-----------
interval: -0.0128610134124756
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 90.8123422472749
distance : 113.473282606026
-----------
interval: -0.00315600633621216
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 2000.0
distance : 180.768761850842
-----------
interval: -0.00381100177764893
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 2000.0
distance : 180.768761850842
-----------
interval: -0.0131250023841858
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 219.000225316427
distance : 0.763731059143118
-----------
interval: -0.0137189626693726
desiredAccuracy: -1.0
accuracy: 219.000225316427
distance : 0.763731059143118
```

any solution ?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: I don't see any code that generates the `distance:` log.

Comment: i didn't add it above cause it have some confidential data

Answer (score 0):

You may simply be expecting more accuracy than can be delivered. First, the phone initially uses other on-board sensors than the GPS. Second, the GPS system itself is not particularly accurate. Thus, even if you are stationary, you may expect small changes over time in where the phone thinks you are, both as different sensors warm up and simply because the most accurate sensor, the GPS, is not really all that accurate.

Comment: Is there any test i can add to avoid it ?

Comment: I need stable distance when my device not moving

Comment: "I need stable distance when my device not moving" I'm telling you that you won't necessarily get it. Haven't you ever been sitting still looking at your position in the Maps app or Google Maps and seen the position shift a little? I certainly have. It's just the nature of the thing.

Comment: Yes but in my app when the distance > 80m i do something so i need to have 0m when i don't move. my app not working likewhat i excpected like that

Comment: But I'm telling you that the accuracy you are asking for is simply not there. GPS cannot reliable distinguish between distance 79m and distance 81m — it doesn't have enough accuracy for that. If the idea is do something when the user crosses the barrier of about 80m distance, why don't you use Region Monitoring? That's what it is for, after all.

Comment: Is possible to know if my device is moving or not?

Comment: Only within the limits of the hardware and the technology that it uses. You can never be 100% sure that the device has / hasn't moved a meter or so. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133112/discussion-between-youssef-z-and-matt).